# Visual studio 2012 fails: CompatibilityMode : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, windows-8.1

Guys I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2012 in Win8.1 but unfortunately I face this error:

**Compatibility Mode : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try Setup again**

Could you please help me how to fix it step by step?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to installation (.exe) file.
2. Right Click on that file.
3. click on **Properties** option.
4. Then select to **compatibility** .
5. Check the option **Run this program in compatibility mode for** : and select for Windows 8.
6. In Settings Check the **Run this program as an administrator**.
7. finally ok and apply this setting and the .exe again.

I hope this will work surely.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from this [link](http://edd.stefancamilleri.com/2013/02/13/windows-program-compatibility-mode-is-on-turn-it-off-and-then-try-setup-again-how-to-uninstall-an-app-if-this-happens/)

1. Run the uninstaller until it fails
2. Go to task manager
3. Call up the context menu for the installer process (right-click)
4. Select ‘open file location’
5. This will open the package folder
6. Call up the context menu for the uninstaller executable
7. Select the ‘compatibility’ tab
8. Disable all compatibility settings over here

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you are trying to install the program from iso.
Extract it first to a folder, then install it from the folder. It worked for me.